# Spring RestTemplate SSL

Tags: spring, ssl, https, resttemplate

I have written simple app which uses Spring RestTemplate to Another REST API.
Sample :

```
  SomeClassresponse = restTemplate.postForObject("https://rest-endpoint.com", body, SomeClass.class);
```

"https://rest-endpoint.com" is using SSL. But my application is not, however according spring documentation RestTemplate "Spring's central class for synchronous client-side HTTP access.". So I'am using Client, as far as I understand I don't need to use SSL for data protection from sniffing packets? Or I'am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct.

The server hosting the RESTful endpoint is responsible for providing SSL. The SSL handshake occurs before your client delivers the payload. During the SSL handshake, the server shares its public asymmetric key with the client, and retains its private asymmetric key which it never shares with anybody. These keys are used to establish a single session key which will be used for encrypting all communication (except for IP addresses) during the session.

You can verify this with a network protocol analyzer such as Wireshark which allows you to inspect packets traversing your network. Run Wireshark and capture the packets that your client sends to the endpoint and you should see that they are encrypted.

Comment: Thank you, for great explanation